# How / can I controll my python code inputs through a webserver?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, webserver, raspberry-pi3

I am making a project that is suposed to be some sort of smarthome solution. My code is written in python and I wish to controll the inputs of for example a timer to switch of the lights and set a wakeup alarm through a website on my lokal network. I plan on using a raspberry pi (3B+) for the hosting.

Is there a way that lets me give inputs and se the outputs on the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a html form and have the user (you) submit it when you make changes, this is the method I would recommend.

You could also use JavaScript on the webpage to automatically send a request to the server on value changes (in an HTML form) for it to configure the server.